# SSIS: DT_NUMERIC is unsigned int with a "separate sign". Is it signed or not?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2005

Here are two slightly different definitions of DT_NUMERIC from msdn

An exact numeric value with a fixed precision and scale. This data type is a 16-byte **unsigned** integer with a separate sign, a scale of 0 - 38, and a maximum precision of 38.

An exact numeric value with a fixed precision and scale. This data type is a 16-byte value with a separate sign, a scale of 0 to 38, and a maximum precision of 38.

What does separate sign mean?
Is it signed or not?
If it is not signed, how to indicate it is with this 'separate sign'?

Answer (score 1):

DT_NUMERIC is SIGNED. You're right, the definition of "separate sign" is not very clear! But you can put a signed integer in such a field and it will work.

Comment: how the hell do you shove a DT_NUMERIC into an SSIS variable when there is no decimal or any type other than double and double doesn't work when you try to shove a DT_NUMERIC into an ssis variable using double or anything else.